# Dynamic div change alternatively in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-5.6

Here i am generating dynamic div i want to execute div first and second alternatively in PHP as dynamic values comes.. please help me related this.

here $count=$content_faq['number'];count of the result

```
 <?php
foreach($content_faq['rows'] as $howit){

    $count=$content_faq['number'];
    $title=$howit->title;
    $images=$howit->image;
    $description=$howit->description;
    for($i=0; $i < $count;$i++)
    {
    if($i % 2){ //remove quotes around 0

       ?>
<!-- div first  -->

<div id="<?php echo rtrim($title); ?>" style="height: 400px; margin-top: 40px;">
     <section >
        <div class="container about-intro" >
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="image1_work">      
                    <img class="img" height="380px" width="100%" src="<?=SITE_MEDIA?>images/howitwork/<?php echo $images?>" alt="image" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="" data-aos="fade-up">
                    <?php echo $description; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!-- closing of section is misplaced -->
</div>
    <?php } else {?>

<!-- div Second  -->

<div id="<?php echo rtrim($title); ?>" style="height: 400px; margin-top: 40px;">
 <section >
    <div class="container about-intro" >
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="" data-aos="fade-up">
                <?php echo $description; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="image1_work">      
                <img class="img" height="380px" width="100%" src="<?=SITE_MEDIA?>images/howitwork/<?php echo $images?>" alt="image" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<?php } } }  ?>
```

My `if and else` condition not working in that case whats wrong there can anyone please help related this..

I want if id =1 then if part div execute, if id=2 cos its divisible and reminder is 0 then else part to be executed.. but i am not getting the same result what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: what is the difference between two divs? I am unbale to find-out. They both are identical. BTW you need to change `if` condition like this:- `if($id %2 ==0){`

Comment: I will change the second div after the code .. but condition not working i change ...

Comment: Any solution ??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A job for the wonderful modulus operator!

Grab the array id with your foreach loop:

```
foreach ($content_faq['rows'] as $id=>$howit) {
```

And then use the modulus to alternate

```
if ($id % 2)
```

This will evaluate to 0 and 1 alternately, which we know are false and true.

Comment: not working.....

Comment: @sweta  what is the difference between two divs? I am unbale to find-out. They both are identical.

Comment: Make sure the entities you're iterating over have a property called id. If not, you can just get it from the numeric indexes of the array you're iterating through:

foreach($content_faq['rows'] as $id=>$howit)

Comment: edited my second div ..

Comment: Any solution ??????

Comment: did you try $id=>$howit like I said above? also remove your definition of $id so you're not overwriting it

Comment: Got any feedback?

Comment: Also, your `</section>` and `</div>` tags at the end of section 1 are out of order.

Comment: i did this i am getting the result exact but getting twice the result .. why maybe it because of foreach or for loop ???

Comment: see my updated code........

Comment: Get rid of that for loop. Read my comments again about how to modify the foreach and your modulus

Comment: can ou please update my code ????

Comment: I added the foreach line to my answer above. You also need to remove your for loop.